# Lookup text against a list to find largest value in python

Tags: python

I have a list of items and I would like to return the one with the greatest severity i.e. The input could be "Rainy|Icy|Windy"

and the list of possible inputs could be (in order of severity): sunny, cloudy, windy, rainy, icy.

With the above input I would like to output only Icy as it is the most sever.

I have tried something like:

```
dictionary1 = {'sunny': 0, 'cloudy': 1, 'windy': 1, 'rainy': 2, 'icy': 3}
    with open(Conditions_csv, 'wb') as fw:
        writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',')
        header = ['Date','latitude','longitude','Condition']
        writer.writerow(header)
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            conditions = row[3].split("|")


        for item in sorted(dictionary1.keys(),reverse= True):
            name = dictionary1[item]
            if name in conditions:
                print row
                print name
                writer.writerow(row + name)
db.close()
```

my output for the above will be:

```
(18/12/2017,45,-85, Rainy|Icy|Windy)
Icy
(18/12/2017,45,-85, Rainy|Icy|Windy)
Rainy
(18/12/2017,45,-85, Rainy|Icy|Windy)
Windy
(18/12/2017,47,-88, Rainy|Windy)
Rainy
(18/12/2017,47,-88, Rainy|Windy)
Windy
(18/12/2017,40,-84, Icy|Windy)
Icy
(18/12/2017,40,-84, Icy|Windy)
Windy
```

all I want to reuturn is:

```
(18/12/2017,45,-85, Rainy|Icy|Windy)
Icy
(18/12/2017,47,-88, Rainy|Windy)
Rainy
(18/12/2017,40,-84, Icy|Windy)
Icy
```

Comment: What exactly do you have a problem with here?

Comment: updated my question to explain better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I used for my answer FYI:

```
with open(Conditions_csv, 'wb') as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',')
    header = ['Date','latitude','longitude','Condition']
    writer.writerow(header)
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        conditions = row[3].split("|")
        Final = max(conditions, key=lambda s: dictionary[s])
        myList= row[0],float(row[1]),float(row[2]),Final
        writer.writerow(myList)
db.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

The built-in `max` function lets you pass an optional `key` argument that does what I think you're asking for:

```
>>> severities = {'sunny': 0, 'cloudy': 1, 'windy': 1, 'rainy': 2, 'icy': 3}
>>> max(['sunny', 'cloudy', 'windy', 'rainy', 'icy'], key=lambda s: severities[s])
'icy'
```